# How to find if infinite series converges uniformly using M test.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

So, here is the series: $$\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty} \arctan(x^6ne^{-nx^2})$$ 
I try to find sup series by deriving the main term:
 $$\frac{1}{1 + (x^6ne^{-nx^2})^2} \cdot n(6x^5e^{-nx^2} - 2nx^7e^{-nx^2})$$

but I think I did something incorrectly because I can't express $x$ out of this. Function $\arctan x$ is not bounded by a constant so I cannot get the sup series by bounding the function, maybe I can use as a bounding series something like $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \arctan(x^6 n )$, but still I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in[a,b]$ then
$$ \forall x\in\mathbb{R},\left|\arctan\left(x^6ne^{-nx^2}\right)\right|\leqslant x^6n e^{-nx^2}\leqslant b^6ne^{-na^2} $$
and the series $\sum b^6ne^{-na^2}$ converges, thus the series converges uniformly on the segments of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How do you know that the series $\Sigma b^6 ne^{-na^2}$ converges?

Comment: Because it is a $o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$.

Comment: @Tuvasvien Do you mean that $\frac{1}{n^2} \ge b^6ne^{-n^2} \forall n \in N$? Also, is it because $n^2 \le c^n$, where $c \in R$?

Comment: It is because $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}n^2\times b^6ne^{-na^2}=0$.

Comment: Here is some elaboration on the inequality $|\arctan(t)|\leq t$. We may use the Mean Value Theorem to obtain $|\arctan x - \arctan y| = |\frac{1}{1+z^2}(x-y)|\leq |x-y|$ where $z$ is some number in between $x$ and $y$. Plugging in $(x, y) = (t, 0)$ gives the desired bound.